# Retrieve Xml attribute using XElement

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

How to read the values from the `XML` - below is the `XML` that I am reading I want to read value of ID and answer

```
<d:Answer xmlns:d="http://www.test.com/" d:title="abcd">
  <d:question id="2.1" answer="test"  />
  <d:question id="2.2" answer="test"  />
  <d:question id="2.3" answer="Yes"  />
</d:Answer>
```

I am using Xelement to read the values but not able to find

Comment: Please show your current code.

Comment: XElement myele = MyXml [where my MyXml] has the xml I want to do something like MyXml.Element("question") where id ="2.1" as i want to access particular question id

Comment: Don't post it as a comment, update your answer instead.

Comment: can any one provide some help on this

Comment: I meant you should update your *question*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var xml = @"<d:Answer xmlns:d=""http://www.test.com"" d:title=""abcd"">
  <d:question id=""2.1"" answer=""test""  />
  <d:question id=""2.2"" answer=""test""  />
  <d:question id=""2.3"" answer=""Yes""  />
</d:Answer>";

XNamespace ns = "http://www.test.com";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var question = doc.Descendants(ns + "question")
                  .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == "2.1");
```

Comment: i am getting error message in FirstorDefault - no extension method  is accepting a first argument of type xElement

Comment: You need `using System.Linq;` at the top of your .cs file.